# How can I add the contact details in the prototype to my code?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

The page is loading fine but, how can I add the contact details in the center of prototype to the center of the Appbar and the bottom navigation bar? Can anyone tell me how can I add that..

Updated the full code as requested in the comments.

```
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
        with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
      String title = 'Tabar / BottomNavigationBar';
    
      TabController _tabController;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _tabController = TabController(length: 5, vsync: this);
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
        _tabController.dispose();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              bottom: PreferredSize(child: Container(),
                  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(45.0)
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              title: Image.asset('images/logo1.jpg',
                height: 50.0,
                width: 70.0),
            ),
            body: TabBarView(
              controller: _tabController,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              children: [
                TopTabBar(),
                Center(
                  child: Text('Accounts',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0)
                  ),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Text('Service',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0)
                  ),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Text('Products',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0)
                  ),
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Text('Log Out',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0)
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: Container(
              color: Colors.amber,
              child: TabBar(
                controller: _tabController,
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                 borderSide: BorderSide(width: 0.0),
                ),
                labelColor: Colors.white,
                labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0),
                tabs: [
                  Tab(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                    text: 'Home',
              ),
                  Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.account_balance),
                  text: 'Accounts',
                  ),
                  Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home_repair_service),
                  text: 'Service',
                  ),
                  Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle_rounded),
                  text: 'Products',
                  ),
                  Tab(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.logout),
                  text: 'Log Out',
                  ),
            ],
          ),
         ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class TopTabBar extends StatefulWidget {
      TopTabBar({Key key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _TopTabBarState createState() => _TopTabBarState();
    }
    
    class _TopTabBarState extends State<TopTabBar>
        with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
      TabController _tabController;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose(){
        super.dispose();
        _tabController.dispose();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.amber,
              child: TabBar(
                controller: _tabController,
                indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(width: 0.0),
                ),
                indicatorColor: Colors.white,
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                labelColor: Colors.white,
                indicatorWeight: 5.0,
                tabs: [
                  Tab(
                      text: 'Contact Us'
                  ),
                  Tab(
                      text: 'Nearest Branch'
                  ),
                  Tab(
                      text: 'Nearest ATM'
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

[This is my prototype and the interface generated by the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjrzI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
body: Column(
        children: [ 
          TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          children: [
            TopTabBar(),
            Center(
              child: Text('Accounts',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0)
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Text('Service',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0)
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Text('Products',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0)
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Text('Log Out',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0)
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Center(ContactDetailsWidget())   
          ),
         ],
        )
```

Add the above code on the body, Here the remaining space will use by your custom widget ContactDetailsWidget where you can display anything